# How to send webcam video + audio to rtsp/rtmp server

Tags: c#, rtsp, rtmp

I'm looking for a method to send video and audio to the rtsp/rtmp server. It should be compatible with notebook webcams and USB webcams. I would like to do it in C#.

I found some library called rtmpclient, but it looks it can't send a message to the server. I found also a framework to support webcams that gives a posibility to do an action for every captured frame. But I can't find any similar solution to send a voice with the image.

How can I send the video and audio to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://net7mma.codeplex.com/ ( I am the Author )

It supports Rtsp and Rtp and not Rtmp however it could support Rtmp with some changes. Depending on what you want to achieve it may be able to do it already... You can possibly fake the Rtmp Packet as a RtpPacket and the library wouldn't care.

If you need Rtmp specefically check out

http://www.broccoliproducts.com/softnotebook/rtmpclient/rtmpclient.php

or

http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/netconnectionrtmp.html

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: I found the broccoliproducts library and it can't send messages to the server.

Comment: Is there really a way to stream webcam live by your library? I saw examples about re-streaming rtsp streams and streaming pictures sets only.

Comment: If the webcam supports Rtp or Rtsp yes, if the camera gets you jpeg frames then also yes :)

Comment: Hmm... so there isn't any way to 'merge' audio and video in one rtp/rtsp packet and easily send it to the server? I meant webcam built in notebooks and I don't know it supports this kind of protocols.

Comment: You mean to mix or mux... You can use the Base Media Library for that...

http://basemedia.codeplex.com/

Please conciser though that Rtp is separate audio and video end points. I don't see why you couldn't combine them however existing encoders and decoders which are complaint will probably not recognize the data or at least ignore the portion it does not recognize in the stream. The normal task to do is demux when sending and to mux when receiving. If you need anything else let me know!

Comment: I mean mux. I want to use DirectX Capture library. It gives me one frame with video and audio within. I consider how to send it to the rtmp server easily.

Comment: For Rtmp I really can't say however you should be able to tell where the audio ends and the video starts and then encapsulate them as required.

Comment: I can send rtp or rtsp packets to the server too.

Comment: If you can send Rtp packets then my library is all you need. Depending on the video format you might have to packetize the data into RtpFrames from the byte[] containing the samples. If you can send JPEG Format packets and have the ability to pass a System.Image my library again has everything you need. If you only have a byte[] then you will manually need to implement a packetizer for the format you desire. All in all 90 - 100% of the work is there and done in my library depending on what you need to accomplish.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26079/discussion-between-daropl-and-jay)