# C# client to stream video to youtube

Tags: c#, youtube, video-streaming, rtmp

I am trying to do a C# client application to stream video files to youtube, I found the following API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started

But I don't see any sample code to stream the video... I only find the sample code to create the object `Stream` and `Broadcast` and then `binding` them. But how do I stream the video? Is there any samples about that?

If there isn't examples of that, how can I stream a video given `server URL` like `rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321896/how-to-send-webcam-video-audio-to-rtsp-rtmp-server